# offset for back to top anchor link

Tags: html, wordpress, animation, offset, scrolltop

I am using wordpress and I wanted to create a scroll to top button so I added this code to a HTML widget in the header widget area of my site :

```html
<div id="top"></div>
<style>html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}</style>`
```

I then added this custom menu item to the footer menu : `#top`.
The scroll works great, except that it doesn't scroll to the very top of the page. But in my case, instead of a sticky header I have a social icons header, see screenshot : https://ibb.co/NFsgJ1H.
Can someone help me add code that will make scrolling until the top of this header ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use javascript something like this. can refer to this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) for this one

```js
const toTop = document.getElementById('toTop');

toTop.onclick = () => {
window.scrollTo({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
}
```

```html
<button id="toTop">Go To Top</button>
```

To include that code in the wordpress, you can add this to your functions.php

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_go_to_top');
function add_go_to_top()
{
   ?>
<script>
window.onload = () => {
    // add above javascript here
}
</script>
   <?php
}
```

Comment: But then were would you advise adding this code, and how should I link to it in the footer menu ? is this possible to do in HTML or css ?

Comment: You can use wp_enqueu_script to insert this code. And you add your button using add_action('wp_footer', 'your_callback')

Comment: where is wp_enqueue_script file located ?

Comment: OK,  it adds the button to the footer but when you click on it it doesn't do anything. But I was thinking of the same design of the scroll to top button, not as a button but as a menu item, aligned with the footer menu. I just asking if there's HTML code that I can add to the HTML widget, that will make the scrolling a bit higher, or until the end of the header  ?

Comment: I changed the answer, then you can add your button in your footer.php and make sure it the id property is "toTop". Thanks

Comment: OK, I think the problem's resolved. It may be that I didn't have the issue from the first place, the problem was that the admin bar was covering the social icons header, as if it if the scrolling is being stopped before it, so for all users that are not logged in and have the floating admin bar, the scrolling works great !! Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I now have a plugin that's doing the scroll offset, this is why I asked this question, I'm trying to get rid of it because it can be done in a more efficient way. Anyway there's this code in a JS file of this plugin. When I delete it it doesn't affect the smooth scrolling and the scroll offset.

```
    app.scroll = function( scrollTo ) {
    app.$html_and_body.stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': scrollTo // scroll and offset
    }, 900, 'swing', function( evt ) {
        app.initialScroll = app.isScrolling = false;
        app.$html_and_body.trigger( 'hash_link_scroll_offset.complete', evt );
    } );
```

I also found this code in a php file of the plugin, and when I delete it the smooth scrolling and scroll offset is stopped, so perhaps we can somehow combine the code and use it :

```
public function enqueue_js() {
    $min = defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ? '' : '.min';
    wp_enqueue_script( 'hash_link_scroll_offset', self::$url . "assets/js/hash-link-scroll-offset$min.js", array( 'jquery' ), self::VERSION, true );
    wp_localize_script( 'hash_link_scroll_offset', 'hlso_offset', array( 'offset' => get_option( 'hash_link_scroll_offset', 0 ) ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And were should I enter the JS code ? And would it work If I changed the code to something like this :, and then instead of the code in the functions.php I'll keep the #top menu item ?

```js
const toTop = document.getElementById('toTop');

toTop.onclick = () => {
window.scrollTo({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
}
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>
```